# How do I convert a battery's 3.7 V, 2.7 A input to 24 V, 400 mA output? 12 V, 800 mA would also work

Tags: dc-dc-converter, battery-operated

I want to use a single Li-ion cell to drive a 24 V, 10 W PTC heater cartridge in a cost-effective manner with closed loop control from a MCU (RPico + 10 kΩ NTC thermistor).

Is boost or boost-buck suitable here? Are there modules that satisfy the 3 A, 3.7 V specs and are under 10£ (if not, I still would be curious)?

Are there any safety concerns here? Might I need a flyback diode due to induction if doing boost-buck?

I'm not really expecting 96% efficiency. 70%+ is fine.

[image: Circuit outline]

Comment: Note first that you're asking roughly for **96%** or more efficiency, then besides being a step-up circuit it has to be one of the very good around, I fear that no easy switchers would sustain a reasonably stable output. But I may be wrong ;D

Comment: (You currently allow for 3 A in the question body, but the title still shows 2.7 A. For an output of 9.6 W at 70%, the input current would be much closer to 4 A.)

Comment: Your M1 would effectively be output disconnect, but id G out is connected to ground anywhere else, you will have problems. Try to find a boost converter with output disconnect and just an enable pin towards your MCU to save you some problems.

Comment: Where did 3.7V and 2.7A come from? An old-style li-ion battery cell is half-charged and sold at 3.7V. It is 4.2V when fully charged. It is destroyed if you allow it to discharge to below 3.0V. It might or might not produce 2.7A because it is rated at 2.7Ah (Amp hours) and can produce 0.27A for 10 hours.

Comment: the 3.7V 2.7A came from the fact that I had a 10W heater cartridge I want it to drive, with PWM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No reason to do a buck-boost here, a boost will work just fine. The main reason you would use a buck-boost over a boost is if you expect the input voltage to rise above the targeted output voltage.

With such a high voltage gain, you won't get the efficiency you are asking for. The specs you are suggesting would require a 96% efficiency, you'll likely get something closer to 70-80%, depending on what specific IC and inductor you chose.

Also, you do not want to be enabling and disabling the regulator at 10Hz. DC-DC regulators have lots of inductance and capacitance, so they don't switch on and off particularly well. Instead, add a high-side PMOS in series of the output of the regulator and connect that up to the 10Hz PWM signal. This will give you a much cleaner PWM output.

One thing to consider is if you can put some battery cells in series. If your are using multiple Lion cells, putting them in series will allow a much lower voltage gain, allowing increased efficiency and therefore longer battery life.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to minimise space so cell count is non-negotiable. I am not so worried about efficiency, so anything above 70% is fine, maximising would be good ofc. *edit accidentally submit early..  If I use the high side PMOS will I incur losses while the PWM signal is inactive

Comment: @BenK - You can use a N-Chanel MOSFET at the output too. Remove the ground from the PTC heater is not a problem.

Comment: Okay interesting @MikroPower! Thanks

Comment: Will this work with a cheap boost step up though from 3.7V to 24V or will I need more expensive components

Comment: When the PWM signal is low, the PMOS will be turned off, so there will be no current load on the regulator. One thing I didn't thoroughly explain is you will need another NMOS on the gate of the PMOS to convert down to the 3.3V logic level. Look up high-side MOSFET and there will be plenty of example circuits you can reference.

Comment: @BenK Electrons don't care about dollar bills, they care about the specifications. What is the part number for the "cheap" regulator you are looking at?

Comment: Also, I totally second @MikroPower's suggestion, low side NMOS switches are much easier to manage, though for some applications the ground wire can't be isolated (usually when using chassis ground for everything, which is common in automotive applications)

Comment: [MT3608 (but probably counterfeit)](https://kunkune.co.uk/shop/power-converter-modules/mt3608-voltage-step-up-adjustable-boost-converter-module/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144683/discussion-between-ben-k-and-hmnbvcxz).

Answer (score 3):

A StepUp is the best choice.

Do not switch the StepUp regulator with 10Hz on and off.
12V would be better than 24V if you have the option.

If you want to regulate the heating-power, than switch the output on and off from the StepUp regulator.